# incrond does not execute custom script

Tags: incron

I tried to set up automated processing of imported pictures and videos from the digicam.

**Custom Script**

```
me@mymachine ~ $ ll /home/me/scripts/autorename-avmedia-exif.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 603 Aug  7 22:50 /home/me/scripts/autorename-avmedia-exif.sh*
```

Contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Argument
if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
    # Only one argument
    file=$1

else
    # No argument
    echo "Usage: $0 target-file"
    exit 1
fi

/bin/echo "$0 started" > /home/me/tmp/autorename.log

exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -P '-filename<CreateDate' -d "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S%%-c.%%le" "$file"

echo "exiftool returned: $?" >> /home/me/tmp/autorename.log
```

**Incron Permissions:**

```
me@mymachine ~ $ sudo cat /etc/incron.allow
me
root
```

**Incron Watch:**

```
me@mymachine ~ $ incrontab -l
/home/me/Bilder/Import IN_CLOSE_WRITE /bin/bash /home/me/scripts/autorename-avmedia-exif.sh "$@/$#" > /home/me/tmp/autorename-avmedia-exif.log
```

**Syslog:**

```
Aug  7 22:36:26 mymachine incrond[1391]: (me) CMD (/bin/bash /home/me/scripts/autorename-avmedia-exif.sh "/home/me/Bilder/Import/DSC01037.JPG" > /home/me/tmp/autorename-avmedia-exif.log)
```

**Problem:**
Nothing happens. The script is not executed.

When copy past'ing the line from syslog into a terminal, the script works without a problem.

Replacing the script call with `touch /home/me/tmp/test.incron` works and the test file is created.

So this has to be an environmental problem, but I already prefixed the script call with `/bin/bash` and added full paths. What else is missing?

Comment: Run `(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >incron.environment` via incron, and via terminal (change the `incron.environment` filename). Compare the two environments.

Comment: @waltinator thank you for your hint; while your command didn't worked either (see my answer why), I was able to debug the problem now ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you waltinator for your help, this pushed me into the right direction.

I don't know what the problem previously was, but as soon as I added the output redirection `> /home/me/tmp/autorename-avmedia-exif.log`, it couldn't work, cause incron seems to not know about it and hands this part over to the script as arguments. There my script failed, as it expects only one argument and there was no logging for the else case.

Just to be clear: the script was called successfully, but it exited at the top, due to a wrong number of arguments.

I found this out with putting `touch /home/me/incron#.test` lines all over the script, while `#` was an incrementing number.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353752/incrontab-output-to-file-not-working